# is it possible to write an app the hides other apps for defined time?

Tags: android, dalvik

I want to write an android app where the user can choose other app X to hide from his apps list

(home screen and apps list) for Y time.

The user chooses X and Y.

If it is possible - what term should I google?

will it presist even after phone shut down?

Comment: This would be open to considerable misuse, would it not?

Comment: Why would a user want to do this?

Comment: It is not possible to hide or prevent apps from launching but you could look into the ActivityManager - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom launcher that implemented this. It would "hide" the application by not showing the launcher icon for it - but the application could still be launched other ways.

Comment: do i need a rooted device?

Comment: No, a launcher application doesn't require root.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write an application that hides other apps without root access. This would be considered a serious security vulnerability in the application framework if it were possible.

Comment: thanks. And what about not hiding but showing popup alert when pressing certain apps? or any other work around

Comment: btw, say my device is rooted. How would I search programming my above question to a rooted device

Comment: I don't believe the recents API exposes any ability to set click listeners when certain applications are selected by the user. That might also even be considered a security vulnerability as well (since it would allow third party applications to spy on a user's day-to-day application usage, etc.). I'm not sure how you would search for something like this... my guess is that you'd have to be pretty lucky to find something on the internet that can walk you through the exact step-by-step.